# Not able to Publish Ionic 1 app to Google Play store with new 64-bit support requirement

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, android-studio, ionic-v1

I have developed an APp in Ionic 1 Cordova Android platform and have been successfully publishing to Play store till 15 days back.
But now with the new requirement of Google to mandate 64 bit support for all apps, I am not able to publish the same to play store.

1. I tried removing and adding android platform again.
2. added 
   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.8
   as required by Ionic platform
3. The new APK generated in Path ~\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
   Earlier the build used to show here 
   ~\platforms\android\build
   Is this the right path?
4. The new APK file opens on the device or emulator and displays a blank screen. Is there any error in the Android and Cordova configuration

My Ionic Config as as below
**Ionic:**

```
   Ionic CLI         : 5.2.4 (C:\Users\Kriskross\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.1
   @ionic/v1-toolkit : 2.0.7
```

**Cordova:**

```
   Cordova CLI       : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (39 plugins total)
```

**Utility:**

```
   cordova-res : 0.6.0
   native-run  : 0.2.8
```

**System:**

```
   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Program Files\Android)
   NodeJS            : v10.16.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.10.3
   OS                : Windows 7
```

**build.gradle :**

- Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
  distributed with this work for additional information
  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
  software distributed under the License is distributed on an
  "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
  KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
  specific language governing permissions and limitations
  under the License.

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    //This replaces project.properties w.r.t. build settings
    project.ext {
      defaultBuildToolsVersion="28.0.3" //String
      defaultMinSdkVersion=19 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.4
      defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
      defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Expected the Appp to run properly which is not happening

Comment: This might help: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit
You can also limit your SDK to version 27 in the manifest. This will give you until August 1, 2021 to update your app with 64 libs, but will limit the number of devices you can install to